# I'm having trouble with a text file being marked as a binary

Tags: linux, grep

I have an executable that generates a text file as its output.  The problem is that the text file comes out with a binary file flag of some sort.  The result is something like this:

```
$ grep "grep string" output_file.txt
Binary file output_file.txt matches.

$ grep -a "grep string" output_file.txt
[correct results]
```

Some reading has indicated that grep looks for a null character in the first thousand or so bytes, then determines from that whether or not a file is 'binary', so my question is two-fold:

1. Is there an easy way to strip null characters from my files (I can do this as part of my post-processing) to ensure that grep works correctly without the -a flag?
2. Is there something obvious I should look for in my code to prevent null characters from being written to the file?  I've looked through the code quite thoroughly and I don't see any obvious culprits.

   .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can answer at least the first question. If you're using Unix/Linux you can use tr

```
tr -d '\000' < filein > fileout
```

where \000 is the null char. You can also strip all non-printable chars as you can see on the example here: ["Unix Text Editing: sed, tr, cut, od, awk"](http://seismo.berkeley.edu/~rallen/resources/UNIXcmds/sed_tr_cut_od.html)

Regarding your second question, I don't know which is your programming language but I'd search for uninitialized variables which could be end being printed to the output file.

Comment: I would vote this up if I could, but I'm apparently too new.  :-/

Comment: I found a null string in my output.  I ran this tr script and did a visual diff; quickly found the problem.  I'll upvote this if/when I get enough reputation to do so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to make a guess....

Your program writes the file in UTF-16, an encoding of Unicode that uses two bytes for each character. Every second byte is, most of the time, a null.

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 < filein > fileout
```

will convert it to UTF-8, which most coreutils are comfortable with.

Comment: Interesting, and I didn't know this about UTF-16. A question about this command - what exactly does the conversation remove from or do to the file? How will it behave in the use case of [my question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1359385/consequences-of-removing-nul-characters-from-a-text-file)?

Comment: @Hashim: It doesn't quite _remove_ anything; it reads values in one representation and writes the same values out in another. (Much like converting between hex and octal, or between PNG and BMP.) UTF-16 represents each codepoint value as a fixed-length two-byte code (or a pair of two such codes), which naturally has to be padded with a 0x00 byte if the value is below 256, while UTF-8 represents the same value as a variable-length code which doesn't require null-padding. How it'll behave with your file depends on whether your file is UTF-16 to begin with.

Comment: @Hashim Is there a way of determining whether a file is UTF-16? Doing `file myfile.txt` simply shows the file as `data`.

Comment: If it's text and looks like text in your text editor, look at what encoding the editor has detected. Try to perform the conversion, and check if the _result_ still looks like text in your text editor. Or do a hexdump of your file, if you see that "every second byte" is 0x00, that almost always means UTF-16.

Comment: Unfortunately opening the file in an editor is out of the question as the files I'm working on are too large - all more than 10GB. If there are no NUL bytes in the second column of a hexdump is it safe to conclude that the file is definitely not UTF-16?

Comment: It may be first or second column (depending on UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE). For mostly-Latin1 text it will be there consistently. For other scripts – Greek, Hangul, etc. – it won't be there because the values are ≥256 and both bytes are fully in use. So it's a possible test but _not_ a definite conclusion. (Note that the conclusion might also be that it's not a plain text file in the first place!)

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using **strings** tool, which is actually even more powerful than just to "fix" encoding or null chars, it can fetch text data from any real binary, so

$ strings output_file.txt | grep "grep string"

usually quite handy to quickly find something in binary file, e.g.

$ strings firmware.bin | grep VERSION